# What is the meaning of the 4 return values from net.input_info[input_blob].input_data.shape?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openvino

First I have try to read directly from the documentation [here](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2021.3/ie_python_api/classie__api_1_1IECore.html#a0d69c298618fab3a08b855442dca430f) and searching online and I don't still don't understand about what is the return value actually means when loading openvino models.

```
    core = IECore()
    net = core.read_network(model=model, weights=weights)
    input_blob = next(iter(net.input_info))
    out_blob = next(iter(net.outputs))
    net = ie.load_network(network=net, num_requests=2, device_name=self.deviceName)
    n, c, h, w = net.input_info[input_blob].input_data.shape
```

What is actually n, c, h and w ? I see some sample code actually just never use the n and c. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the NCHW or NHWC is the data format for activations (images).

Activations consist of channels and a spatial domain, 1D, 2D or 3D(dimensions).

Spatial domain together with channels form an image.

During the training phase images are typically grouped together in batches.

Even if there is only one image, we would still assume there is a batch with batch size equal to 1. Hence, the overall dimensionality of activations is 4D (N, C, H, and W) or 5D (N, C, D, H, and W).

If you want to know in-depth what they are, you'll need to understand [this concept](https://oneapi-src.github.io/oneDNN/dev_guide_understanding_memory_formats.html).